# How do I crawl an IP address and get list of websites on it in PHP?

Tags: php, web-crawler

Let's say I have an IP address for a specific web server say it's 67.222.134.101, how do I get a list of all the websites on that web server using PHP?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this (certainly not a standard way that would work against all types of web server)

Comment: You cannot. No webserver is configured per default to reveal all virtualhosts. Best you might get is http://apache.org/server-status an access log excerpt to extract domain names from.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this is to run a full-scale web crawler, which harvest domain names and check which IP addresses they point to. That way, you can map the IP addresses to domains you've found.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. Although there is a workaround: there are some websites which collects the reverse names of an IP address. If your ip is collected by one of these sites, you can crawl the list from them. Ofcourse after you got a permission to clone their database.

Example: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

Building on Eduard7's answer, you can use DNS tools to look up a DNS name from an IP address.

Keep in mind, this does *NOT* list all web sites at that address; it is only listing domain names that are registered with PTR records. So it may not include all web sites or even any web sites at all. It may also include domain names that do not have web sites associated with, e.g. if a domain name is ftp.mydomain.com, we probably wouldn't find a website with that name.

Anyhow, with those caveats, here's how you use `dig` (Linux or Unix) to look up domain names from an IP address:

```
/Users/mhaase $ dig -x 67.222.134.101

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> -x 67.222.134.101
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43186
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;101.134.222.67.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
101.134.222.67.in-addr.arpa. 43200 IN   PTR 67.222.134.101.tailormadeservers.com.

;; Query time: 106 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Aug 21 10:14:22 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 95
```